# SUM of unique months with 2 Dates in Excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet with 3 columns: ID, Month/Year of Program Entry, & Month/Year of Program Exit.

Basically, we have clients entering and exiting programs and I'm trying to figure out the unique SUM of Months that they've been enrolled.

I've gotten close, but seem to be stuck.

Please see the link below for an example and my desired result. Thank you.

Example & Desired Result:
[image: Example & Desired Result]

Comment: Where are you stuck?  What have you done so far?

Comment: I'd suggest a vba solution.

Comment: As you and WD11 have pointed out, I'm stuck on the non-sequential/overlapping months. Any idea what a VBA solution might look like? I'm not sure where to begin with that. Thank you!

Comment: I would use a dictionary to create a list of the UserID's, and within each each dictionary item, create another dictionary (perhaps using a Class object), to contain a unique list of the related months.  Then go through the dictionary and output the user ID and the count of the contained months.

Comment: I'd love to do that, but I've not worked with VBA and am a bit pressed for time. Is this a project that you or someone you know might be interested in? If so, would you be able to provide me with an estimate to move forward? Thanks again.

Comment: I was able to find someone who made a custom macro that seems to be working. Thank you, Ron!

Comment: I'm happy I was able to point you in a useful direction.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a Pivot-Table on your data with User-ID in Row Labels entry and exit in column labels and instead of the Sum function use Min (in entry column) and Max (in exit column).

[image: Your reduced data]

[image: Result]

From there on it's no big step to rerun your month sums one more time.

Comment: What happens with non-sequential months, in your algorithm?

Comment: really a tough one - will/would have to check for overlapping time periods as well and include that as additional feature in the data and the pivot-table .. maybe better idea after I get some sleep

Comment: Appreciate your help! The non-sequential months have been the tricky aspect of this.